# How to add plugin activity in the menus?

Tags: plugins, menus, installation

I have Installed CM answer plugin, but how can I add that as a menu at the top?

Note: I can install plugin but the problem is that I don't know the way to add the plugin into the menu or a page.

Comment: As asking recommendation for plugin is an off-topic here, I removed that portion of your Question and edited your actual question for a good answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your dashboard->appearence->menus
Select the menu where you want your link for this plugin

Now create a custom link from the custom Links box at left side as:
enter the url as:http://www.your_site_name/answers/
and enter the label as anything you want to display in your menu

add this custom menu in any postion in your menu and you are done!!